# C# to VB Conversion Question

Tags: c#, vb.net

Can anyone help me convert this to vb.net the converter I used doesnt work right and really dont know how to convert it.

```
public Person CurrentPersonCancellable
    {
        get
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Getting CurrentPersonCancellable.");
            return _CurrentPersonCancellable;
        }
        set
        {
            // Store the current value so that we can 
            // change it back if needed.
            var origValue = _CurrentPersonCancellable;

            // If the value hasn't changed, don't do anything.
            if (value == _CurrentPersonCancellable)
                return;

            // Note that we actually change the value for now.
            // This is necessary because WPF seems to query the 
            //  value after the change. The combo box
            // likes to know that the value did change.
            _CurrentPersonCancellable = value;

            if (
                MessageBox.Show(
                    "Allow change of selected item?", 
                    "Continue", 
                    MessageBoxButton.YesNo
                ) != MessageBoxResult.Yes
            )
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Selection Cancelled.");

                // change the value back, but do so after the 
                // UI has finished it's current context operation.
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                        new Action(() =>
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(
                                "Dispatcher BeginInvoke " + 
                                "Setting CurrentPersonCancellable."
                            );

                            // Do this against the underlying value so 
                            //  that we don't invoke the cancellation question again.
                            _CurrentPersonCancellable = origValue;
                            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPersonCancellable");
                        }),
                        DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle,
                        null
                    );

                // Exit early. 
                return;
            }

            // Normal path. Selection applied. 
            // Raise PropertyChanged on the field.
            Debug.WriteLine("Selection applied.");
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPersonCancellable");
        }
    }
```

The converter gives me this and where I am having an issue is where it calling the application.Current.Dispather.BeginInvoke.

```
Public Property CurrentPersonCancellable() As Person
Get
    Debug.WriteLine("Getting CurrentPersonCancellable.")
    Return _CurrentPersonCancellable
End Get
Set
    ' Store the current value so that we can 
    ' change it back if needed.
    Dim origValue = _CurrentPersonCancellable

    ' If the value hasn't changed, don't do anything.
    If value = _CurrentPersonCancellable Then
        Return
    End If

    ' Note that we actually change the value for now.
    ' This is necessary because WPF seems to query the 
    '  value after the change. The combo box
    ' likes to know that the value did change.
    _CurrentPersonCancellable = value

    If MessageBox.Show("Allow change of selected item?", "Continue", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) <> MessageBoxResult.Yes Then
        Debug.WriteLine("Selection Cancelled.")

        ' change the value back, but do so after the 
        ' UI has finished it's current context operation.
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(New Action(Function() Do
            Debug.WriteLine("Dispatcher BeginInvoke " + "Setting CurrentPersonCancellable.")

            ' Do this against the underlying value so 
            '  that we don't invoke the cancellation question again.
            _CurrentPersonCancellable = origValue
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPersonCancellable")
        End Function), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, Nothing)

        ' Exit early. 
        Return
    End If

    ' Normal path. Selection applied. 
    ' Raise PropertyChanged on the field.
    Debug.WriteLine("Selection applied.")
    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPersonCancellable")
End Set
End Property
```

Comment: People might be more responsive to your question if you highlight a particular problem you're having rather than asking to have your work done for you.

Comment: Please sort out your formatting and try and reduce the amount of code - is all of that code really necessary when it appears your converter only has an issue with a particular line?

Comment: "The converter gives me this and where I am having an issue is where it calling the application.Current.Dispather.BeginInvoke." And what *is* the issue you're having? This would be much easier to answer if you (a) only showed the relevant portion of code, and (b) actually said what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

`Function` as used in the `BeginInvoke` cannot contain multiple statements.
You need to move that into a seperate function and call/take the address of it as appropriate.

There are many things (especially to do with lamdas and anonymous methods) one can do in C# that one just cannot do in VB.Net.

There are many language elements that **are not** interchangeable.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Maybe I need to do it a differant way.  I have a listbox on my view and I am using MVVM and didnt want anything in the code behind since that defeats the purpose but I need to be able to cancel the selectionChanged on the list box if they havent applied there changes.  I need to do this in VB.net since my company wont allow other languages.

Comment: @spafa9: <trite_response>Sounds like you need another company</trite_response>

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Public Property CurrentPersonCancellable() As Person
    Get
        Debug.WriteLine("Getting CurrentPersonCancellable.")
        Return _CurrentPersonCancellable
    End Get
    Set
        ' Store the current value so that we can '
        ' change it back if needed.'
        Dim origValue = _CurrentPersonCancellable

        ' If the value hasnt changed, dont do anything.'
        If value = _CurrentPersonCancellable Then
            Return
        End If

        ' Note that we actually change the value for now.'
        ' This is necessary because WPF seems to query the '
        '  value after the change. The combo box'
        ' likes to know that the value did change.'
        _CurrentPersonCancellable = value

        If MessageBox.Show("Allow change of selected item?", "Continue", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) <> MessageBoxResult.Yes Then
            Debug.WriteLine("Selection Cancelled.")

            ' change the value back, but do so after the '
            ' UI has finished its current context operation.'
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(New Action(of Person)(addressof dispatcherCallerHelper), _
                                                       DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, _
                                                       new Object() {origValue})

            ' Exit early. '
            Return
        End If

        ' Normal path. Selection applied. '
        ' Raise PropertyChanged on the field.'
        Debug.WriteLine("Selection applied.")
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPersonCancellable")
    End Set
End Property

private sub dispatcherCallerHelper(origValue as Person)
    Debug.WriteLine("Dispatcher BeginInvoke " & "Setting CurrentPersonCancellable.")

    ' Do this against the underlying value so '
    '  that we dont invoke the cancellation question again.'
    _CurrentPersonCancellable = origValue
    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPersonCancellable")
end sub
```

On a side note, for your OnpropertyChanged function, you should consider using static reflection :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36262/Getting-Fun-with-NET-Static-Reflection.aspx

Cheers !